# Método DAO retornando atributos de mais de um objeto

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, padrão-dao

Estou com uma dúvida no uso de DAO. Se eu precisar retornar um conjunto de atributos de 2 objetos? Vamos dizer que tenho um DAO categoria que possui um método que além dos atributos da categoria precise retornar junto o atributo id de produto como ficaria o retorno do método do DAO categoria? O retorno seria um array? Ou poderia ser uma classe predefinida com stdClass?
Todo exemplo que procuro é sempre um simples CRUD.

Um exemplo:

```
public function opcoesDoFiltro($idCategoria){
        try{
            $pdo = $this->database->getPDO();

            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT e.endereco_string_bairro, e.endereco_string_cidade, f.facilidade_string_facilidade "
                . "FROM(((endereco AS e INNER JOIN contato AS c ON e.endereco_int_idContato = c.contato_int_id) INNER JOIN "
                . "facilidade as f ON f.facilidade_int_idContato = c.contato_int_id) INNER JOIN anuncio AS a ON "
                . "c.contato_int_id = a.anuncio_int_idContato) WHERE a.anuncio_int_idCategoria = ? "
                . "GROUP BY e.endereco_string_bairro, e.endereco_string_cidade, f.facilidade_string_facilidade" );

            $stmt->bindValue(1, $idCategoria, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
            if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
                foreach($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $opcao){
                    $gruposDoFiltro[] = $opcoesDoGrupoDoFiltro = new stdClass();
                    $opcoesDoGrupoDoFiltro->endereco_string_bairro = $opcao["endereco_string_bairro"];
                    $opcoesDoGrupoDoFiltro->endereco_string_cidade = $opcao["endereco_string_cidade"];
                    $opcoesDoGrupoDoFiltro->facilidade_string_facilidade = $opcao["facilidade_string_facilidade"];
                }
                return $gruposDoFiltro;
```

Esse código está em categoriaDAO porém retorna atributos de endereço e facilidades que são necessários. endereco e facilidade tem os seus DAOS. Talvez deixe mais claro a pergunta.

Comment: pode ser o `array` e pode ser também `stdClass`. Agora tudo isso vai depender o porque de retornar essas informações...

Comment: Então virgílio tenho um DAO que faz um apanhado de 3 innerjoin pra retornar essas propriedades mescladas ao controller, o view precisa exibir essas informações juntas acho que isso deve ser algo comum pra quem usa DAO não? Porém foi ai que veio a dúvida pois cada DAO é separado retornando objetos distintos de acordo com a sua regra de negocio mas e pra  esse caso que os atributos estão mesclados?

Comment: você cria as DAO com os métodos em comum Insert, Update, Delete, Read, depois disso pode criar um [FACADE](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A7ade) para resolver esse problema.

Comment: Virgílio mas tenho inúmeros casos assim, vou ter que gerar várias fachadas pra intercambiar vários DAOs, innerjoin nâo poderia ser uma solução retornando um array com os atributos necessários das classes que montam o rol da resposta?

Comment: é complicado opinar, sem ver o seu caso a fundo. Eu lhe dei um caminho, mas, tem vários e talvez até melhores.